# ASP.NET MVC3 Html.Action containing a form

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, child-actions

I have a pod on my page that contains a form.

I have used this pod in a similar way to the following:

```
@Html.Action("Pod","Home")
```

There is some business rule checking in the Pod's HttpPost action which handles the form post. If this business rule fails, I add an error to the model state.

The problem is, that when the business rule fails to validate. I return a View from the pod action, which shows just the pod on a blank page.

How can I correctly reuse a form like this and still have server side validation of this business rule (requires a db hit to validate)?

Comment: We are already to MVC3?  Where the heck have I been?   Oh.  wait, working on a legacy ASP classic site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to AJAXify the form in the `Pod` partial:

```
<div id="pod">
    @Html.Action("Pod","Home")
</div>
```

and inside `Pod.cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Pod", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "podForm" }))
{
    ...
}
```

finally AJAXify it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#podForm').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $('#pod').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The last thing to make sure is that the POST action returns the Pod.cshtml as a partial view. Two possibilities:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pod(PodViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    ...
}
```

or in the `Pod.cshtml` partial:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but you need to add "return false;" to your javascript code after the ajax call.